# AWS Elastic Beanstalkl Nodejs React Deployment Error babel: command not found

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, babeljs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

trying to launch a react node app on elastic beanstalk and experience server side errors

my folder set up is

```
-client
-server
  - index.js
  - other files etc
-package.json
```

inside my package.json, my scripts are listed as

```
{

  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    "build-server": "babel -d ./build ./server -s",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-server",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./build/index.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

when running eb deploy, i get errors

```
Jan 28 04:51:45 web: > api@0.0.0 start /var/app/current
Jan 28 04:51:45 web: > npm run build && node ./build/index.js
Jan 28 04:51:45 web: > api@0.0.0 build /var/app/current
Jan 28 04:51:45 web: > npm run clean && npm run build-server
Jan 28 04:51:45 web: > api@0.0.0 clean /var/app/current
Jan 28 04:51:45 web: > rm -rf build && mkdir build
Jan 28 04:51:45 web: > api@0.0.0 build-server /var/app/current
Jan 28 04:51:45 web: > babel -d ./build ./server -s
Jan 28 04:51:45 web: sh: babel: command not found
```

Not sure how to fix this as my package.json already includes babel dependencies

Also, from other online tutorials, I see guides stating to output index.js as a compiled file and including a Procfile which overrides npm start and runs the compiled file, but this approach doesnt work for me as my server includes 10+ files.

```
"babel index.js --out-file index-compiled.js",
```

any help appreciated. thanks

Comment: Are your Babel dependencies in dependencies or devDependencies, and which is being used on EB? Usually you would compile ahead of time, not on the server. And what do you mean by "this approach doesn't work"? You're doing the exact same thing pre-start (the build-server script), you'd just usually do it as part of a build process.

Comment: added my dependencies, I tried that as well but end up with different errors, "cannot find modules of"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have to set aws environment variable

NPM_USE_PRODUCTION = false

to install dev dependencies

Comment: To set this environment variable should I put this in environment properties in the elastic beanstalk console? Or should I throw this in .ebextensions? Also if I do the later, I already have a file named nodecommand.config under .ebextensions, that holds:

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
    NodeCommand: "node server.compiled.js"

So what syntax would I use to add this new variable?